# crop image save in internal storage and get bitmap from uri

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I write a code crop image.The image maybe a little big,so I use `intent.putExtra("return-data", false);` and `intent.putExtra("output", outputUri);` So I should decode the `uri` to get bitmap.Just like this(omActivityResult)

```
InputStream is = null;
is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(outputUri);
Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

I first make External Storage to store the crop image.It work well.

```
outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/upload.jpg"));
```

But I need to store it in Internal Storage.I follow the [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

to save in Internal Storage.The code follow.

```
FileOutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        os = openFileOutput("upload.jpg", 0);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (os != null)
        {
            try
            {
                os.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }

    }

    outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "upload.jpg"));
```

the `avatar` will be null.I have read many questions in stackoverflow but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure that `is` is not `null` after `is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(outputUri);` ? Are you sure that `outputUri` isn't `null` too?

Comment: store External Storage is not null but store Internal Storage is null. I think somewhere i wrong ,but I can't find it @ Andreu Rodríguez i Donaire

Comment: @Andreu Rodríguez i Donaire I try again it won't be null use External Storage